# Does AllJoyn Studio Extension support generation of methods with arguments?

Tags: alljoyn, windowsiot

I've tried to create a simple project using AllJoyn to expose an interface to my Garage Door via a Raspberry Pi 2 running Windows 10 IoT.

The relevant Introspection XML file is as follows:

```
<node xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://allseenalliance.org/schemas/introspect.xsd">
    <interface name="com.hastarin.GarageDoor">
    <!--<annotation name="org.alljoyn.Bus.Secure" value="true" />-->
    <description language="en">Interface for controlling a garage door.</description>
    <property name="IsOpen" type="b" access="read">
      <annotation name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Property.EmitsChangedSignal" value="true"/>
      <description language="en">Is TRUE if the door is open.</description>
    </property>
    <property name="IsPartiallyOpen" type="b" access="read">
      <annotation name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Property.EmitsChangedSignal" value="true"/>
      <description language="en">Is TRUE if the door is only partially open for air flow.</description>
    </property>
    <method name="Open">
      <description language="en">Opens the door if it's closed.</description>
      <argument name="partialOpen" type="b" direction="in">
        <description language="en">
          If TRUE, the door will only be partially opened to allow air flow.
          If FALSE, the door will be fully opened.
        </description>
      </argument>
    </method>
    <method name="Close">
      <description language="en">Close the door if it's open.</description>
    </method>
    <method name="PushButton">
      <description language="en">Will trigger the push button on the garage door.</description>
    </method>
  </interface>
</node>
```

Unfortunately the generated service interface does not include the argument for the Open method.

```
 public interface IGarageDoorService
  {
    IAsyncOperation<GarageDoorOpenResult> OpenAsync([In] AllJoynMessageInfo info);
    IAsyncOperation<GarageDoorCloseResult> CloseAsync([In] AllJoynMessageInfo info);
    IAsyncOperation<GarageDoorPushButtonResult> PushButtonAsync([In] AllJoynMessageInfo info);
    IAsyncOperation<GarageDoorGetIsOpenResult> GetIsOpenAsync([In] AllJoynMessageInfo info);
    IAsyncOperation<GarageDoorGetIsPartiallyOpenResult> GetIsPartiallyOpenAsync([In] AllJoynMessageInfo info);
  }
```

The full source code for the project can be found on GitHub:
https://github.com/hastarin/HastPiControl

Can anyone tell me if I'm doing something wrong, or if perhaps this is a limitation of the AllJoyn Studio Extension?

Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue.  Then I stumbled across an example that used `<arg>` instead of `<argument>` for the element name. It worked for me - haven't had a chance to look into it further...

Comment: Thanks, I was following examples from [an article on Channel 9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Internet-of-Things-Blog/Creating-AllJoyn-Producers-and-Authoring-AllJoyn-Introspection-XML) which showed it as being `<argument>`.

Everything else shows it as `<args>` - [Events and Actions](https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/api-guide/events-and-actions) | [D-Bus Specification](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#introspection-format) | [Extended Introspection Format](https://wiki.allseenalliance.org/irb/extended_introspection_xml)